# Kendo ajax grid is not showing data that it is receiving

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I cannot get my grid to render the data it's retrieving.  I have the following code in my controller, and verify it gets returned by watching the network tab in the browser:

```
 [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SavedSettings_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var ret = DBFunctions.SavedStringInfos.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        //return Json( ret); made everything lowercase?
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);//newtonsoft

    }
```

My grid is defined like this:

```
    Html.Kendo().Grid<SavedStringInfo>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(data =>
        {
            data.Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)

                .Model(x => x.Id(p => p.IPAddress))
                .Create("SavedSettings_Create", "Home")
                .Read("SavedSettings_Read", "Home")
                .Update("SavedSettings_Update", "Home")
                .Destroy("SavedSettings_Destroy", "Home");
        })

        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .ToolBar(t => t.Create().Text("Add New Device(s)"))
        .Columns( columns =>
        {
            columns.Command(x => { x.Edit(); x.Destroy(); });

            columns.Bound(m => m.StreamTo).Title("Stream To").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(m => m.StringName).Title("String Name").Width(200);
            columns.Group(g =>
            {
                g.Title("Channels");
                g.Columns(gc =>
                {
                    gc.Bound(m => m.StartChannel).Title("Start").Width(100);
                    gc.Bound(m => m.EndChannel).Title("End").Width(100);
                });
            });
            columns.Bound(m => m.DisableFrameLimiter).Title("DFL").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(m => m.IPAddress).Title("IP Address").Width(160);
            columns.Bound(m => m.MacAddress).Title("MAC Address)").Width(160);
            columns.Group(g =>
            {
                g.Title("Aspect Ratio");
                g.Columns(gc =>
                {
                    gc.Bound(m => m.XYAspectRatio).Title("XY").Width(100);
                    gc.Bound(m => m.XZAspectRatio).Title("XZ").Width(100);
                });
            });
        })
    )
```

I have also verified the grid's datasource is actually empty by this:
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data
as well as
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItems()
and inspecting the tree.

I'm apparently missing an important setting but I don't know what.
Here's the returned json (captured in fiddler)

```
{
"Data": [
   {
     "ID": 1,
     "StringName": "Line in bedroom",
     "StartChannel": 1,
     "IPAddress": "192.168.4.166",
     "MacAddress": "a8:03:2a:3e:76:95",
     "StreamTo": true,
     "XYAspectRatio": 0.8,
     "XZAspectRatio": 0,
     "DisableFrameLimiter": true
   },
   {
     "ID": 2,
     "StringName": "Right poles",
     "StartChannel": 1,
     "IPAddress": "192.168.4.36",
     "MacAddress": "a4:e5:7c:c4:75:01",
     "StreamTo": true,
     "XYAspectRatio": 0.45455,
     "XZAspectRatio": 11.36364,
     "DisableFrameLimiter": true
   },
   {
     "ID": 3,
     "StringName": "Left poles",
     "StartChannel": 1,
     "IPAddress": "192.168.4.37",
     "MacAddress": "a4:e5:7c:5e:6f:f9",
     "StreamTo": true,
     "XYAspectRatio": 0.5,
     "XZAspectRatio": 11.36364,
     "DisableFrameLimiter": true
   }
 ],
 "Total": 3,
 "AggregateResults": null,
 "Errors": null
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing obvious. I would strip it down to the basics to try and work out where the error is. Remove all the columns except for StringName, set the id to just be x.Id. Can you get that to render? Then add everything back one piece at a time.

Comment: i tried that already.  One single column, id = id.  No luck.  It renders if i switch it to server grid, but i've never done filtering/sorting on a server grid before.

Comment: Indeed, the configuration seems correct. If I pass the JSON to the configuration [the Grid renders data as expected](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mxkoGSFx42XAl6zA20). Try adding an error event handler to the DataSource. If it fires, than for some reason the response might be perceived as an invalid JSON ( though it seems to be valid) and data will be not rendered.  Also try making the SavedSettings_Read ActionMethod accept only POST requests and see if that helps.

Comment: i'll look at it this evening.  I may have an incompatible version of json installed

Comment: I'm going to self-answer.  I got it working but for the love of everything, I don't actually know why the answer I'm about to post fixed anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone can chime in and explain why this fixed my problem, I'll change my accepted answer to theirs.
Inside my Program.cs, where you configure your Web Application Builder, I added a configuration parameter to NewtonSoft to use

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddKendo();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
            }
        );

var app = builder.Build();
```

Then, I made the following change to my Controller

```
 public ActionResult<string> SavedSettings_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var ret = DBFunctions.SavedStringInfos.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(ret);
    }
```

Now, the sharp-eyed among you may see why this is confusing to me.  Json doesn't belong to NewtonSoft, and the serialize object call didn't work with the change in Program.cs, and both changes were required to fix the issue.  If anyone can explain WHY this fixes it, points to you.  Until then, I hope this helps someone else who is stuck.